# social.framework doesn't include classes

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am adding the social.framework in the "Link Binary With Libraries". On running the project, getting error that "Social/SLRequest.h" file not found. I have checked the social.framework in the project hierarchy but it doesn't contain any header class (Social.framework is empty). please help me why the social.framework is Empty ?

Note: Social.framework is not available in Link Binary With Libraries. I have to add that from the "Add Other" option. Social.framework located in my downloads and it contains the header classes there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xcode 4.5 or later. social.framework is available from iOS 6.0. To use Social framework apis include the framework as

```
#import <Social/Social.h>
```

Comment: I am using xcode 4.6...i dont know why these (social,account,adsupport)frameworks are not visible in my xcode.I have downloaded these from github and including these with "Add other" option.

Comment: i think your project setting it proper or not, just create new project and check whether these frameworks are available.

Comment: go to project settings and check Base SDK is set to iOS 6.x

Comment: no..not available in new project too..something wrong with my xcode?

Comment: may be try reinstalling if you have the back up.

Comment: just checked it using xcode 4.5 and those frameworks goes available now. Thanks a lot @pradeepa